# create scatter plot for each two dimension for ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, while-loop, scatter-plot

I have ndarray with the shape (13, 2236, 1866). I would like to create scatter plot for each dimension with all the other dimension, e.g dim1 +dim2, dim1 + dim3, dim1 +dim4 ...sdim2+dim3, dom2+4........ until I get scatter plots for all the possibilites.

Right now I have scripts that uses while loop but that ofcurse doesn't find all the matching possibilites .
#array= the ndarray

```
d=0
while d+1<13:
    x=array[d].reshape(-1)
    y=array[d+1].reshape(-1)    
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, linewidth=0)
    plt.scatter(x, y,s=5, linewidth=0)
    plt.xlabel('B{band1}'.format(band1= str(d+1)))
    plt.ylabel('B{band2}'.format(band2 = str(d+2)))
    plt.show()
    d=d+1
```

here I get the possibilites of B1+B2,B2+B3,B3+B4...
I also tried to create list of the dimensions and the use for loop:

```
dims=np.arange(0,13)
```

and then" for d in dims" to run the while loop but that also doesn't give all the possibilites.

My end goal: to create all the possible scatter plots for all the dimensions

Comment: what is array in your code?

Comment: @JacksonPro arra is the ndarray. i'll add it in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I have used  the function from [here](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y104/tessapy):

```
dims=np.arange(0,13)


def tessa(source):
        result = []
        for p1 in range(len(source)):
                for p2 in range(p1+1,len(source)):
                        result.append([source[p1],source[p2]])
        return result

pairings = tessa(dims)
print("%d pairings" % len(pairings))

        
        
for i in pairings:
    xd=i[0]
    xy=i[1]
    x=array[xd].reshape(-1)
    y=array[xy].reshape(-1)    
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, linewidth=0)
    plt.scatter(x, y,s=5, linewidth=0)
    plt.xlabel('B{band1}'.format(band1= str(xd+1)))
    plt.ylabel('B{band2}'.format(band2 = str(xy+1)))
    plt.show()
```